# Diagonalization hermitian matrices julia vs fortran

Tags: fortran90, numerical-methods, lapack, julia

I have a program written in Fortran and in Julia, one of the cases I have symmetric matrices
and I get results more or less similar with both programs. When I switch to a case where I have hermitian matrices, the program in Julia and the program in Fortran give me different stuff. I would guess that maybe the difference comes from the diagonalization procedure, in Fortran I use:

```
ZHEEVD(..)
```

while in Julia I simply use:

```
eig(matrix)
```

The first thing that I notice is that `ZHEEVD` fixes the first row of the eigenvector matrices to real numbers (no imaginary part), while `eig` fixes the last row to real numbers.

Any idea how to overcome this tiny differences? Any more info that can be useful when dealing with julia's linear algebra built-ins?

Answer (score 1):

Digging in to the Julia methods (the `@less` macro is very handy for this), you'll find that it eventually calls the `LAPACK.syevr!` method, which in the `Complex128` case [is a wrapper for the `ZHEEVR` LAPACK method](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/linalg/lapack.jl#L2918) (scroll down a bit to see the actual definition).

If you'd prefer to keep using `ZHEEVD`, you can access it via the `ccall` interface: see the manual section on [Calling C and Fortran code](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/). The LAPACK wrappers linked above should provide plenty of examples (LAPACK comes as part of OpenBLAS, which is included in Julia, so you shouldn't need to install anything else).